# How do I properly add existing source code files to my Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm new to iPhone development and I'm still getting familiar with the Mac dev environment, including Xcode.  I want to add some 3rd party code to my iPhone project, but when I add the "existing files" to my Xcode project, I'm presented with a dialog box that has far too many options that I don't understand and, as such, my project isn't working.  When I `#import headerfilename.h`, I get a build error that reads `headerfilename.h: No such file or directory`.

[alt text http://joecrotchett.com/images/misc/fileadd.jpg](http://joecrotchett.com/images/misc/fileadd.jpg)

1. Can anyone explain to me what all these options mean or give me a link to some documentation that can?  I'm having a hard time finding anything in Apple's docs.
2. Which options do I want to choose to add existing source code files to my Xcode project?  I should note that the source code files that I'm trying to add are located in my project/Classes/frameworkname/ directory.
3. After they're added, do I need to reference this new code directory in my project settings anywhere (i.e. some kind of header file directory variable)?

Thanks so much!

**Update:** I found the following answers/responses on the apple dev forums that were very useful and helped me fix my issue...

> To make it simple :
>   - if you do not check the copy option, the file stay where it is.
>   - if you check it, it is copied in your project folders In the first case
>   (what it seems you are doing) you need
>   to tell the compiler that the header
>   files are in another directory :
>   - project info -> build -> search paths -> User Header Search Path : add
>   the directory from where you took the
>   header file   Hope this will help

---

> You have discovered the most confusing
>   dialog box that ever came out of
>   Cupertino.   Six years of Xcode, and
>   this thing still is partly a mystery
>   to me. To even get that far, I had to
>   make many test projects to try and
>   reverse-engineer what this thing does.
>   The "Copy" box means that it will copy
>   the files as they are right now, into
>   the project. If this box is not
>   checked, then it just references those
>   files during a build and copies them
>   as they are at THAT time. For source
>   code, you want the Copy box checked.
>   The "relative to" is a total mystery
>   to me and I can't help you with that.
>   I usually leave it however it is
>   already set. Does it mean relative to
>   where they are on disk, or the
>   arrangement in Xcode, or in the
>   bundle? Who knows.   The last 2 radio
>   buttons SEEM to mean that it will
>   either re-create the folder structure
>   of the folder you are adding, or just
>   put "fake" folders in Xcode that point
>   to the real folders. This is probably
>   your problem - you are adding source
>   code that is not all at the top level,
>   and when it goes to find it, it does
>   not re-create the hierarchy.   Others
>   can supply a better way, hopefully,
>   but what I would do is put all of the
>   source in one folder and add that,
>   using the Copy box. Then in Xcode you
>   can make whatever bogus folders you
>   want and put the source file names in
>   those fake folders.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_File_or_Folder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copy items into destination group's
>   folder (if needed)

Well, only if you want it to copy the files.  If you are happy with their existing location and don't want it to copy them, don't select it (that's what I do).

> Reference Type:

A total mystery to me

> Text Encoding

Self explanatory

> Recursively create groups for any
>   added folders Create Folder References
>   for any added folders

Leave this as the default and then organize the folders in your Xcode project any way you want.

> Add to targets

If you add an additional target to your project, e.g. for iPhone vs. iPad versions, then not noticing that it has by default added the files to just one of them (at random?) can cause headaches.

Also, make sure you add the new header directory to your search paths in Project Settings > Build > Search paths.  I think that's what's causing your problem.

Hope this helps, I remember how confusing this was to me at first.

Answer (score 4):

This is from the Xcode user guide:

> "The project navigator shows projects, groups, folders, and files:
>
> The project or projects in your workspace window are the highest level
>   of the hierarchy in the project navigator. Open the project’s
>   disclosure triangle to see the groups, folders, and files in the
>   project. Select the project to display the project editor, where you
>   can view and edit project and target settings.
>
> A group appears in the project navigator as a yellow folder icon. The
>   group does not represent a folder on disk. Although you can organize
>   your project in Xcode to reflect the organization of files on disk,
>   moving files into and out of groups does not affect the content of the
>   folders on disk, and moving files on disk into and out of folders does
>   not affect the content of the groups in the project navigator.
>
> A folder is a reference to a folder on disk and appears in the project
>   navigator as a blue folder icon. The contents of the folder in the
>   project navigator reflect the contents of the folder on disk. It’s
>   important to note, however, that the files that appear in a folder
>   icon in the project navigator are not part of your project unless you
>   have added them to the project explicitly (in which case they appear
>   directly under the project or in a group, as well as in the folder).
>   You can view and edit the files in a folder, but to move files in and
>   out of the folder you must use the Finder.
>
> A file in the project navigator is a reference to a file on disk."

Answer (score 2):

I think usually the default option is the best one. If you want to add into some group, you can tick on the "Copy Item to Destination group"

You don't have to change any project settings after adding

And if you want to add the whole framework code, please choose add existing framework

Comment: thanks, vadkhang, but the default options don't work for me.  the source code files appear in my "Groups & Files" pane, but I still can't seem to use them in my project without getting the "headerfilename.h: No such file or directory" build error.

Comment: you're wrong, you actually do need to change the project settings and add a search path for your header files in the Project > Edit Project Settings> Search Paths.  Just FYI.

Comment: Oh, that happens if you want to search header files as well. But I think we can easily add both header files and source files using the feature of adding existing items, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an Framwork Bundle, just add is as one. `Add -> Existing Frameworks`

Comment: thanks, unset, but i'm trying to add source code, not a framework bundle.

Comment: You can't use frameworks (dynamically) linked code on the iPhone, per Apple's dev license.